# Edit a remote web page and save changes

Tags: html, css, browser

Do you know any software (browser extension or add on) which can change and modify any page's css and/or html and save changes locally. And later when I open that page my modifications to be loaded as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [stylish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stylish) for [chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe) and [FF](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that's possible because  the CSS styles can be (and usually are) located on a different file. This is assuming you want to edit the already existing style sheet. Creating style sheets from scratch for the webpage is different.

Comment: not from scratch - maybe a way to automatically add a css wich is located locally and i will manage to override the sites real css.

Comment: You have to do it from scratch using Stylish. This is because CSS style sheets are stored on a text file you can't see (kind of like how you can't see PHP code). If I were you I'd look for something that can guess what the style is based on fonts and things like that in order to compile a CSS style sheet.

Comment: You can see the effects of it but you can't see the actual code. Look I'll use this page's code as an example  view-source:http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_examples.asp Now in there you'll see a line that says <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stdtheme.css" /> This is the CSS file. That's what you need to edit. You can get to it by plugging the file name into it but it takes some doing because they can be stored in different places. For that page they were nice enough to put it here view-source:http://www.w3schools.com/stdtheme.css That though is what you have to edit